# Align inflated view left in Gravity.CENTER Relative Layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a relative layout that is acting as a button with text content that is being changed dynamically. This text is centered in the layout using the `android:gravity="center"` attribute. The issue is that I need to inflate another layout inside the same Relative Layout, but align it to the left. I can inflate the view just fine, but it always shows up in the center (as expected since the layout has center gravity). It looks like this...

[image]

The gray box is the parent relative layout, and the green box is the view that I am trying to align left. I've tried setting the margins to various things - including an offset left of half the width of the parent view - but nothing is working so far. Is there a way to do this? It might be worth adding that the width of the parent Relative Layout (gray box) will vary, so the solution should preferably work regardless of the size.

XML of the green view being inflated:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="20dp"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="@color/pending_color"
          android:paddingLeft="5dp"
          android:id="@+id/ribbon">
```

Code where I am inflating the view into the parent RelativeLayout:

```
        View inflatedView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pending_ribbon, null);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(30, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    inflatedView.setLayoutParams(params);

    this.addView(inflatedView);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, first problem, [don't pass `null` to `inflate()`](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/). Pass in the parent `ViewGroup`, and `false` to indicate you don't want to attach it yet:

```
View inflatedView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pending_ribbon, this, false);
```

Once you've done that, the view should already have LayoutParams and you won't have to set them manually:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParms) inflatedView.getLayoutParams();
```

Add the `ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT` rule to your inflated view (`RelativeLayout` doesn't really use `gravity`):

```
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
```

Then add the view and you should be good to go:

```
addView(inflatedView);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I follow correctly, you have a parent view which is a RelativeLayout, and you need child 1 (a textview) centered, and child 2 (a linearlayout) aligned left?

try:

child 1

```
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    or
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

child 2

```
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

EDIT:

you could encapsulate child 2 in another RelativeLayout

```
    parentlayout
        child1
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >
            <child2
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I tried that and it does not work. The issue is that the parent view (Relative Layout) has centered gravity, and this gravity needs to be able to be set dynamically as well. So with the parent view's gravity being centered, I can't get the child views to align differently.